How to make something like outlet of react-router-dom in angular project?
Like when you call the child component, it is displayed with the component of the parent path a bit like react router-dom and its outlet ?
I'm new with Angular.
For the moment I haven't found a way by reading the official documentation.

He Nomena! Sorry you got some downvotes, if you add some more details of what exactly you're trying to do, you'll have better luck. Screenshots, code-snippets, or excerpts from documentation that help illustrate what you're trying to do.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can do similar way in the angular using router-outlet and children
Here is routing structure
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: ParentComponent, // in this component you should define router-outlet
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ChildrenComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];


Playground link: parent-children-routing-with-outlet
